# im unable to move focus to different verticalfieldmanagers which are scrolling horizontally

Tags: blackberry

im unable to move focus to different verticalfieldmanagers which are scrolling horizontally???

can anyone help me on this issue with a piece of code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the VerticalFieldManagers in  a HorizontalFieldManager and try scrolling it

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL)
{
   public void sublayout(int arg0,int arg1)
   {
      setExtent(width,height);
      // you can set the layouts over here
   }
};
VerticalFieldManager vfm1 = new VerticalFieldManager();
VerticalFieldManager vfm2 = new VerticalFieldManager();
//add some fields to the verticalFieldManagers
hfm.add(vfm1);
hfm.add(vfm2);
add(hfm);
```

Let me know if your problem has solved or not.